# use set_tests_properties from test in other directory

Tags: cmake

(related to [add standard libraries to RPATH for build tree executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54443412))

I have the following directory structure as minimal working example

```
.
├── baz.cc
├── baz.h
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── sub
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── foo.cc
```

`sub` is in practice a git submodule and should not be edited for my specific corner case but remain generic.

`sub/CMakeLists.txt` defines a test that does not run in my setup because a shared library is not added to the RPATH by cmake. To reproduce this behavior, it can be thought be

```
enable_testing()
add_executable(foo foo.cc)
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY SKIP_BUILD_RPATH TRUE)
target_link_libraries(foo ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../libbaz.so)
include_directories(..)
add_test(NAME footest COMMAND foo)
```

(`foo.cc` can be:

```
#include "baz.h"
int main() { 
  return bazinga() - 42;
}
```

let's assume a shared library with the `bazinga` symbol will always be available, e.g. from `/usr/lib`)

My top level `CMakeLists.txt` is

```
add_subdirectory(sub)
add_library(baz SHARED baz.cc)
```

I want to get the `footest` running by manipulating its `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as suggested [here](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2013-February/053726.html). This would be by adding

```
set_tests_properties(footest PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path_where_libbaz.so_is_on_my_target_system")
```

This line does the job when I add it to `sub/CMakeLists.txt`, but fails with the following error when I edit the top level `CMakeLists.txt`

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (set_tests_properties):
  set_tests_properties Can not find test to add properties to: footest
```

given the above reason, I want to do the fixup without editing anything in the `sub`directory.

Is there a way to set properties of tests that are defined in other directories than the current one?

Comment: very late comment, but just to confirm- when you do `set_tests_properties` in the top-level CMakeLists.txt file, you are putting it _after_ the call to `add_subdirectory(sub)`, right?